# Extracting a vendor name into a separate column in a data frame

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a data frame (df) with a column df[‘description] that contains a string of text like so:

```
Compu serve Industries Inc.          584-965-7524              2568                  3/8/2018       100,685,865.78
ABC_Computer Services Inc.              631-692-2571                 3384        2/1/2019       5,625.25
ABCD & EFGH Industries, Inc. 718-995-1040  9759                5/25/2019                        1,963.52
ABC Industries, Inc.                                631-582-2640                      7816         11/16/2000           1,695.66
ABC Corporation  800-242-6229     5584                                     2/27/2018                    30,562.54
```

The number of spaces between the different fields vary in each row. What I’m trying to accomplish is extract each field into its own separate column.  For example, I’ve already extracted Phone, ID, Date and Amount fields.  I can’t figure out how to do the same for the vendor_name.

```
df['Phone']=df['combined_data'].str.extract('(\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{4})')
df['ID']=df['combined_data'].str.extract('(\d{4})')
df['Date']=df['combined_data'].str.extract('(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})')
df['Amount']=df['combined_data'].str.extract('(\$?(?:\d+,)*\d+\.\d+)')
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful to see more than one row of data, to see more possible patterns. Perhaps paste `df.head()` into your question?

Comment: Probably grab everything before the phone number?

Comment: Is there any delimiter between the fields ? Or, possibly there are fields of known type and form that can be used in conjunction with a known number of fields to deduce the unknown field location ?

Comment: No, no delimeter between the fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
pat = r'^(.*?)\s+(\d{3}[-.\s]\d{3}[-.\s]\d{4})\s+(\d{4})\s+(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})\s+(\d[\d,.]*)'
df[['VendorName','Phone','ID','Date','Amount']] = df['Description'].str.extract(pat)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JrYOF2/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Vendor name group: any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\d{3}[-.\s]\d{3}[-.\s]\d{4})` - Phone number group:
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\d{4})` - ID group: four digits
- `\s+` -  1+ whitespaces
- `(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})` - Date group: 4 digits, 1+
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\d[\d,.]*)` - Amount group: a digit and then 0+ dots, commas or digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the company based on the unique phone number regex

`(?m)^[ ]*(.+?)(?=[ ]*\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{4})`

https://regex101.com/r/XzXzh6/1

Readable version

```
 (?m)
 ^ [ ]* 
 ( .+? )                       # (1)
 (?=
      [ ]* 
      \d{3} [-\.\s] \d{3} [-\.\s] \d{4} 
 )
```

Comment: The original approach does not work actually, `df['ID']=df['combined_data'].str.extract('(\d{4})')` will match the 4 digits of the phone number. So, this regex won't help to solve the current problem, but might be useful in general.

Comment: Really, well he didn't ask me to fix that. But if he did, and he wanted to maintain singular expressions, I'd sell him this `(\d{4})(?=[ ]+\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})`, for $50 In fact I'm going to sell my services to the rich.